# How to load spline scene in background in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create 3d website using Spline.
First I created my 3d scene in Spline, then I exported my code.

this is my code, but the scene link is dummy as I cannot share my actual scene

```
import Spline from '@splinetool/react-spline';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
//this is not my actual scene, I cannot share my actual scene here, this is dummy scene
      <Spline scene="https://prod.spline.design/6Wq1Q7YGyM-iab9i/scene.splinecode" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

My scene is little bit big, so it is taking too much time to load, so I want to show Loader and want to fetch/load scene in background.

**What I am trying to do?**
My actual scene is taking too much time to load. So I want to load my complete scene in background so, Once it is completely loaded I want to show it, so till it is being fetched, I want to show simple loader/spinner, spinner should disappear once Scene is completely fetched and ready to show so it will not take too much time to load

**What I tried?**
I tried using lazy load, but this not worked
I also tried by creating promise inside useEffect, but this not worked

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem, but i have found the an answer.
Try this:
Lazy loading
To start loading react-spline after the whole website has finished loading, we can use lazy-loading. This technique can be achieved using React.lazy() in combination with dynamic imports:

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

const Spline = React.lazy(() => import('@splinetool/react-spline'));

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <Spline scene="https://prod.spline.design/6Wq1Q7YGyM-iab9i/scene.splinecode" />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```